# Wix - Setting Compatibility Mode on shortcut for all users

Tags: wix, compatibility, shortcut

I have a msi that has its InstallScope set to "perMachine" and it creates a shortcut which is available to all the users:

```
<Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
   <Directory Id="CompanyShortcutsDir" Name="My Company" />
</Directory>

 <Component Id="CMP_MainExeShortcut"
           Directory="CompanyShortcutsDir"
           Guid="{B857CD9E-XXXX-YYYY-F2090C50C985}">

  <Shortcut Id="MyExeStartShortcut"
            Name="My Product"
            Description="$(var.WIX_PRODNAME)"
            Target="[APPLICATIONFOLDER]MyApp.exe"
            WorkingDirectory="APPLICATIONFOLDER"
            Icon="my.ico" />

  <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveCompanyShortcutsDir"
                On="uninstall" />

  <RegistryValue Root="HKCU"
                 Key="Software\MyCompany"
                 Name="MainExeShortcut"
                 Type="integer"
                 Value="1"
                 KeyPath="yes" />
</Component>
```

and the shortcut does indeed appear for all the users - so far so good !!

But I also have this fragment of code:

```
    <Component Id="CMP_MainExeShortcutCompat"
          Directory="CompanyShortcutsDir"
          Guid="{C748B7C6-XXXX-YYYY-7CB1823774DC}">  


  <RegistryValue Root="HKMU"
         Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers"
         Name="[APPLICATIONFOLDER]MyApp.exe"
         Type="string"
         Value="~ WIN7RTM" 
         KeyPath="yes"/>
</Component>
```

who's purpose is to set the "Compatibility Mode" on the shortcut to be "Windows 7" - but this only happens for the user that installed our product, it doesn't get set on the shortcut for the other users who are likely to login to the PC.

Does anyone know how I can set this flag on the shortcut for all the users ?

Many Thanks,

Chris.

Comment: Have you tried with Root="HKLM"?

Comment: Can you solve this with an application manifest? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371711(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Morten - Yes I tried using HKLM at first, but then it won't compile with "ICE38: Component CMP_MainExeShortcutCompat installs to user profile. It's KeyPath registry key must fall under HKCU"

Comment: Christopher - I hadn't thought of using a manifest, though I will look into that - was hoping someone could come up with a WiX trick that I didn't know about !

Comment: Is the target operating system 32 bit or 64 bit or both?

Comment: bradfordrg - It's one msi that can be run on either 32bit or 64bit operating systems